# zf tool strange behaviour

Tags: zend-framework

I'm trying to use the zf tool to create a new model using the command :

```
zf create model FormRegister
```

it comes up with an error  : 'String could not be parsed as XML'.

The strange thing is that I have an old copy of my project in another folder and the zf tool allows me to perform the operation there just fine. I thought it might be the .zfproject.xml file, so I copied that across and it changed nothing. I know I can create models manually, but it would be nice to be able to use this utility.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the xml with a tool to test if it's malformed or if there's some dirty `&` char (remember that it should be `&amp;` )